# itunesconnect apploader invalid segment alignment issue

Tags: app-store-connect, loader

Guys i want to update my application newest version but App Loader giving me same error all the time and that is

"ERROR ITMS-9000: "Invalid Segment Alignment. This app does not have proper segment alignment and should be rebuilt with the latest version of Xcode. Please contact Developer Technical Support if you need further assistance.""

I am going to crazy. I have Xcode 6 so it's latest version. I cannot find the problem please help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Xcode 6.0.1. Still unsolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great Solution!!

> Workaround: ERROR ITMS-9000: invalid Sement Alignment. This app does
>   not have proper segment and should be rebuilt with the latest version
>   of xcode.

now my app is Waiting for Reviews

First, just be clear some steps.
My setups is   Flash CC 2014 Trial version , Actionsript 3.0 , App loader from Xcode 6.0.1 and  Mac OS 10.9.5  and Adobe Air  15

My Steps

1. Download and Update Adobe Air
    get  adobe.com  es  air
2. Setup new Adobe Air version in Flash CC
   http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/overlay-air-sdk-flash-professional1.html
   and
   http://www.leebrimelow.com/quick-tip-targeting-new-air-sdk-in-flash-cs6/
3. Setup by terminal console  (system linker) Adobe's worker by Pahup

   cd /lib/aot/bin/ld64

   mv ld64 ld64_orig

   ln –s /usr/bin/ld ld64
4. Setups on developer.apple.com/iphone  (From Apple Account)

   - Create Certified p12 and Provisioning for iStore
5. Compile and cross your fingers for approval

Thks.

EDIT: just to be clear  this line  cd /lib/aot/bin/ld64
its from SDK downloaded ok? so for eaxmple   cd  dowload/adobeairk_sdk/lib/aot/bin/ld64

Comment: is this for Adobe Air SDK user only?

Answer (score 1):

An Adobe's worker say:

por Pahup el 25-sep-2014 5:11
It seems there have been changes in way Apple expects the apps to created. We investigated this deeper, and found that the output of our linker (in our toolchain) is no longer being accepted by Apple.

We are working on this to upgrade our toolchain, including the linker. For the time being,  we would suggest you to try using the ‘linker’ available on the system. We have done tests with a couple of apps and it seems to be fixing the problem. Please give it a try and see if it can unblock you. Please note that this workaround is applicable only for Mac platform.

Steps to make use of system linker -

cd /lib/aot/bin/ld64
mv ld64 ld64_orig
ln –s /usr/bin/ld ld64

Before the submission, we recommend to test the application functionality as well. Please keep us posted with more information in this regard. It will help us fix our toolchain sooner and in a better way.

Comment: So what am i suppose to do know? wait?