# IOSApp rejected: Error ITMS-9000 Invalid segment alignment

Tags: ios, apache-flex, flex-mobile, flashbuilder4

I am getting an error while trying to release the application for Apple App Store.

> Error ITMS-9000 Invalid segment alignment

Following the process flow  mentioned on the link below:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2

I am stuck with this for quite sometime now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

The SDKs and the framework details are as follows:

- Flex SDK 4.12.0
- Apple IOS 8
- Adobe AIR 16

I have also mentioned the question on Apache forum but haven't received any reply

http://apache-flex-users.2333346.n4.nabble.com/IOSApp-rejected-Error-ITMS-9000-Invalid-segment-alignment-td9409.html

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26061630/itunesconnect-apploader-invalid-segment-alignment-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 4.14 SDK with AIR 16.0 version It will solve all the Issues.

Comment: thanks Ashish, atleast by using it the ball is now in Apple's court. They atleast have excepted it. waiting to hear from them.

Meanwhile if you can help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094062/spark-datagrid-scrolling