# iOS deployment with Delphi XE7 with error 90209

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe7, firemonkey-fm3, xcode6.1.1

I am trying to upload my app to the iStore.

The upload fails with the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment.The app binary does not have proper segment alignment".
```

I have found that many users get a similar issue with ITMS-9000, but the solutions does not help.

I am using **xcode 6.1.1** with the **Delphi XE7**.

Comment: I think this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/26190873/3202193 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/26105224/3202193

Comment: Hi Ashish.  Unfortunately the provided links does not help.  I have tried both of the solutions as far as possible.  The workaround does not work for Adobe Air as I am working with Embarcadero's compiler.  I have post the issue on the Embarcadero forum but no one replied.

Comment: Ok, Let see other person will see and reply your question. There is many errors comes up with ITMS!

Comment: Do you maybe know what the correct value for DTPlatformBuild key should be in my info.plist for xcode 6.1.1?